# Why doesn't empty() work on input in search bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When clicking the`inviteButton`, the input search bar should clear out, but it doesn't work with my current code.

Am I targeting the element incorrectly?

```js
 $("#inviteButton").click(function(){
  var userName = $("#searchUser").val();
  if (userName.trim() != "") {
    if (userName == myUserName) {
    $("#connectToBox").append("You can't invite yourself");
    $("#searchUser").empty(); // Doesn't work
   } else {
    socket.emit("checkUserConnect", userName, function(data){
     if (data.result === undefined) {
      console.log("No name");
      $("#connectToBox").append("User does not exist");
      $("#searchUser").empty(); // Doesn't work
     } else {
      console.log("name exists");
      $("#searchUser").empty(); // Doesn't work
      $("#connectToBox").append("Invite send");
      UserID = data.result.id;
      socket.emit("connectToUser", myUserName, UserID, currentConversation);
     }
     });
   }
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="connectToBox">
    <label for="search-2">Type in username</label>
    <input type="search" name="search-2" id="searchUser" value="">
    <a href="#" id="inviteButton" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Connect</a>
   </div>
```

Comment: `$("#searchUser").val('')`

Comment: You can't just use methods that sound like they might do something you want - "I want to 'empty' the input" - ah, there's a method "empty()" - that must be it.  Look up what empty does and you'll see it's in the *DOM Manipulation Section* of *Removal*: https://api.jquery.com/empty/

Comment: You can assign an empty string as @freedomn-m suggested. Just do this - $("#searchUser").val('')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To empty an input field you would normally use:

`$('#searchUser').val('')`

Empty is used to clear away child nodes from elements like divs or p tags, but not for inputs.

Reason for that is that the text within an input is not represented as a child node of the element and instead stored on an html attribute of the input tag. Hence `.empty()` does not work for clearing the value.

Comment: This is the correct answer since op ask about `why` but not `how`.

Comment: Thank @Antonvb. Good explanation. Wasn't aware of how `.empty()` works differently

Answer (score 2):

You can clear the input field by using

```
$('#searchUser').val('');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#searchUser').val('');
```

This will work fine according to your application.

> The empty() method removes all child nodes and content from the selected elements. [Src: W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_empty.asp)

According to your requirement you need to reset the value of an input field, for that we have `val()` function. You can assign an empty string and it will work fine. 
Using `empty()` won't work here.

#### Check these examples -

- empty() working correctly -

```js
function emptyOperation(){
    $("div").empty();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="input-field" value="Random string">
</div>
<button onclick="emptyOperation()">Check</button>
```

- empty() as per your code [won't work] -

```js
function emptyOperation(){
    $("#input-field").empty();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="input-field" value="Random string">
</div>
<button onclick="emptyOperation()">Check</button>
```

- Solution to your problem -

```js
function emptyOperation(){
    $("#input-field").val('');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="input-field" value="Random string">
</div>
<button onclick="emptyOperation()">Check</button>
```